# Error when initializing a RavenDB documentstore that contains a machinename in the URL

Tags: initialization, ravendb

I get an error when initializing a RavenDB documentstore that contains a machinename in the URL, combined with specifying a non default database i.e Multitenant. 
I can only get `store.Initialize()` to work if I do not specify a default database.

My ConnectionString is `http://somemachinename:8080;ResourceManagerId=d5723e19-92ad-4531-adad-8611e6e05c8b`

Following code fails

```
var store = new DocumentStore
{
    ConnectionStringName="RavenDB,
    DefaultDatabase="TNW_Grc_CLient",
    EnlistInDistributedTransactions=false
}
store.Initialize(); // fails with the following exception
```

with this message

> Message = "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: g"

**Scenario**:

a) The first time (if the database does not yet exist) this is called, 
the call succeeds and I note that the raw http response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Location: /docs/Raven/Databases/TNW_Grc_Client
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Raven-Server-Build: 427
Date: Fri, 26 Aug 2011 19:45:23 GMT
X-Charles-Received-Continue: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"Key":"Raven/Databases/TNW_Grc_Client","ETag":"00000000-0000-0300-0000-000000000001"}
```

b) The second time  the call fails. Debugging some, it appears the etag header is not sent from
the server **but is somehow expected by the client code:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Raven-Server-Build: 427
Date: Fri, 26 Aug 2011 19:48:10 GMT
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"Id":null,"Settings":{"Raven/DataDir":"~\\Tenants\\TNW_Grc_Client"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify values on the connection string or on the document store properties, not both at the same time.